# how to use like clause with db.query(....) in SQLite

Tags: android

hi i am new to android and got stuck in a problem

i have a table of two fields songname and songhits in my database .Now i want to get  all songs starting with a string say MATCH_STR sorted by songhits in a list.I know the sql query but i dont know how to execute in my android app.pls help me with an example or correct code.

my code :

```
  Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, "songname","songname like %"+MATCH_STR+"%" , null, null,"SongHit", null);
    if (c != null) 
    {

         c.moveToFirst(); 
         int SongNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("SongName"); 
         if (c.isFirst()) 
         { 
                  i = 0; 

                  do { 
                           i++; 
                            String SongName = c.getString(SongNameColumn); 

                            // Add current Entry to results. 
                           results.add(SongName); 
                      } while (c.moveToNext()); 
          }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, "songname","songname like ?" , new String[]{"%"+MATCH_STRING+"%"}, null,"SongHit", null);
```

May be these will one hElp!!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have missed single quote link like operator

```
 Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, "songname","songname like '%"+MATCH_STR+"%'" , null, null,"SongHit", null);
```

check and correct your query

Comment: hi, try using myDB.rawQuery(yourSql). in this you can write your complete query

Answer (score 0):

try below code for search :-

```
public Cursor getROUTINENAME(String search_str) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM TBNAME where COL_NAME LIKE '%"+search_str+"%'";

        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

call above function with string .